# Create view with more models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

hi everyone I have a doubt with the use of forms and models.
I have to create a code that creates records in multiple tables and I don't know how to do it.
my goal is to create a page where I can enter all the data and when I save it creates the various tables filled in with the data provided by the user.

I'm a beginner I still have to learn the mechanism well =)

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Schede, DatiGruppi, Gruppi

class CreaSchedaForm(forms.ModelForm):
nome_scheda = forms.CharField(
    required = True,
    label ='Nome scheda',
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder' : 'nome scheda',
            'autocomplete' : 'off'
        }
    )
)
data_inizio = forms.DateField(
    label='Data inizio',
    widget = forms.DateInput(
        attrs= {
            'type': 'date',
            'class': 'form-control', 
            'placeholder' : 'data inizio'
        }
    )
)
data_fine = forms.DateField(
    label='Data fine',
    widget = forms.DateInput(
        attrs= {
            'type': 'date',
            'class': 'form-control', 
            'placeholder' : 'data fine'
        }
    )
)
class Meta:
    model = Schede
    fields = ['nome_scheda','data_inizio','data_fine']


class CreaDtGruppoForm(forms.ModelForm):
giorni_settimana = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices = DatiGruppi.giorni_settimana_scelta
)
dati_gruppo = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset = Gruppi.objects.all(),
    empty_label = "-",
    required = True
)
class Meta:
    model = DatiGruppi
    fields = ['giorni_settimana', 'dati_gruppo']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def creaScheda(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
  form = CreaSchedaForm(request.POST)
 if form.is_valid():
  scheda = form.save(commit = False)
  scheda.utente = request.user
  scheda.save()

else:
 form = CreaSchedaForm()
context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "crea_scheda.html", context)
```